# onClick button not working javascript/php/jquery mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-mobile

Can anyone tell me why this onClick doesnt work? The function is in a separate .js file and has been tested to work fine. I dont get an error - nothing at all happens.

```
<?php
blah blah
$int = 1;
$listno = 3;
?>

<input type="button" onClick="test(<?php echo $int;?>, <?php echo $listno;?>);" data-theme="mybutton" value="<?php echo $name;?>">

<?php
....
```

Do I need script tags here? Sorry if the php bit is a bit wrong I just typed it to show you - the button is the problem.

Comment: Can you put your code of test() function. Or you can add alert('pass'); as the fist line of the function and see whether you get the alert of not. Also if you use chrome developer tool you will see errors in the bottom of the tool.

Comment: I have added the alert and it doesnt run (I had a similar alert anyway). Sorry I cant post the javascript function - but I have tested it.

Comment: OK. Is there any chance to come $int and $listno as strings?

Comment: Going to be hard to help without seeing how and where the test() function is declared. I would suggest posting your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a test() function defined in JavaScript

Comment: He says "The function is in a separate .js file"

Comment: we can't debug what we can't see

Comment: This should be more like a comment.